# Trabalhar com várias ou uma única base de dados (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, Galera!

Uma empresa me contratou para unificar (e refazer) vários sistemas que possuem.
O trabalho é criar único painel administrativo para vários setores e produtos.

Ao pensar no armazenamento dos dados, me deparei com a seguinte dúvida:
Crio uma **única base de dados para todos os sistemas** ou **uma base de dados para cada sistema?**

Qual é o recomendado? Quais são as boas práticas atualmente? Qual consome menos processamento?
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Sem conhecermos os detalhes mais minuciosos dos seus requisitos, a resposta para cada indagação sua é **"depende"**. Agora, se eu tivesse que apostar, uma base de dados para cada sistema *tende* a ser mais organizado - mas mais uma vez, isso **depende** da sua definição de "sistema".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal seria trabalhar com as bases de dados independentes, porém unificadas, através da normalização de banco de dados relacionais.

Cada setor seria uma base independente e cada base trabalharia com os produtos correlatos. Se necessário, as bases separadas podem ser ligadas através do modelo entidade-relacionamento, onde as informações de uma base podem ser consultadas em outras, tornando assim sua base mais segura, pois as informações estariam "desmembradas", mas sem causar impacto. Outra vantagem é que o tempo de acesso ficaria reduzido significativamente, pois a página acessaria uma base menor, e, se necessário, utilizaria seus campos relacionais para acessar diretamente informações de outras bases.

Na minha empresa, trabalhamos com esse modelo de bases relacionadas desde 2008, e o ganho de produção é muito alto.

Caso queira maiores informações, deixo um link que meu professor de faculdade nos deixou para leitura complementar.

http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~pet/jornal/maio2011/materias/recapitulando.html

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica!